# python google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --host **.22*.74* --port 8000 ./out/app_engine/

Tags: python, google-cloud-sdk

`python google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --host **.22*.74* --port 8000 ./out/app_engine/`

What is the meaning of above command line execution in python? Should I need to edit the file in `src` folder or `out` folder, because those two folders (`src` ,`out`) have same files?

Please explain what is exactly meaning of the above line.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To run your app using the local development server, you should use the command: dev_appserver.py [PATH_TO_YOUR_APP]. More related details are to be found on the "Using the Local Development Server" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server).